# How to set header background to fit appropriately

Tags: html, css

Need help setting the header size so that accommodate the image and text.

I've tried changing the background size using the "background-size" property but it doesn't change.

```css
header {
  background-color: red;
  background-size: 200px 100px;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration-line: underline overline;
  text-decoration-style: double;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

header .pic {
  border: 5px #000 outset;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="pic" src="" alt="" width="200px">
  <h1>Placeholder Text</h1>
</header>
```

The header background appears until the middle of the text and image when I want it to be on the bottom of the text and image (whichever is lower).

Comment: You don't have a background image in your markup. You have an *inline* image.

Comment: Include the appropriate img url inside the src attribute to present the issue as it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the `display: flex`

Try this

```css
/* Reset 
*******************/
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
img { max-width: 100%; }

/* Styles 
*******************/
header { background-color: red; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between; padding: 1rem; }
header .pic { width: 200px; }
header h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration-line: underline overline;
    text-decoration-style: double;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <img class="pic" src="https://sg.fiverrcdn.com/photos/105746482/original/3e2a4ad867ed23117cfda223391c35ab42bb99fc.png">
    <h1>Placeholder Text</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: if you're going to downvote this answer, you need to give an explanation why

Comment: So far this works, I'll keep you updated if anything changes as I am new to html and css. Thank you!

Comment: @VasantKurvari , if this works for you, can you accept this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```css
header {
    background: url("img/index.jpg") ;
    background-color: red;
    background-size: 200px 100px;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration-line: underline overline;
    text-decoration-style: double;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

header .pic {
    border: 5px #000000 outset;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
<h1>Placeholder Text</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want a background image but just a background in the header that covers the header fully (I used the cover and contain properties but they don't do anything).

Comment: ah my bad i miss understood your issue hopefully you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

When you want a background image in a container you do something like this:

```
header {
 background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/400');
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height:100vh;
 width: 100vw;
}

h1 {
 color: black;
 font-size: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Instead of using a normal image tag, you declare you background image in the CSS.

See a working example here: https://codepen.io/Angel-SG/pen/dwOEvy

Comment: Sorry, didn't want a background image but just a background color behind the image and text. I would've uploaded a picture but I can't.

Comment: I have amended the code pen for what you are trying to achieve, have a look, please!